# Topological characterization of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers endowed with the usual topology (**no** allusion to field operations) be characterized? of course, I mean "in purely topological terms".

I would be delighted if such characterization does not involve  path-connectedness (since this notion involves the subspace $[0,1]$ of $\mathbb R$) and cardinality, though I am afraid that Mr. **ZF** will not allow such feat for the latter.

Comment: Suslin's problem?

Comment: Zermelo and Fraenkel are not the same person.

Comment: @user40276: That's not exactly relevant. Suslin problem is about a specific characterization of the real line *as a total order*. There are categorical characterizations in terms of the ordering (as the separable, dense, complete linear ordering without endpoints), but not every topology is induced by a total ordering.

Comment: A few characterizations are given in [this MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76134/). Most of them seem to satisfy your requirements (although I'm not quite sure what you mean by excluding cardinality: is separability allowed?).

Comment: @tomasz: Not *every* topology can be induced by a total order, but the OP is asking about the *usual* topology on $\Bbb R.$

Comment: @tomasz I know, it is just a figure of speech...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real line is the unique connected, locally connected separable metric space such that each point is a strong cut point.  See [this post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76134/topological-characterisation-of-the-real-line).

Note that "metric space" can be replaced by "second-countable regular space" (by the [Urysohn Metrization Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem#Metrization_theorems)), if you want to avoid the use of real numbers.  Indeed, as the MO post states, one can simply replace "metric space" by "regular space" and the theorem is still true.

Comment: +1: I think you mean "locally compact" instead of "locally connected."

Comment: @CameronBuie Would you care to elaborate?  I think "locally connected" is right.

Comment: "Locally connected" is indeed right. Ward's article proving the characterization can be found [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-41.3.191).

Comment: My bad. Forgot that connectedness doesn't imply local connectedness. /facepalm/